# Unable to run X11 session on container with namespace remapping enabled

Tags: linux, docker, x11, alpine-linux, xorg

I have an Alpine Linux container that runs a X server (using host devices with `--privileged`), i've recently enabled the user namespace remapping feature on the daemon (including adding the `--userns=host` to my `docker run` command)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.15

ARG DOCKER_GROUP_ID

RUN apk add --no-cache xhost xinit xorg-server xf86-video-fbdev xf86-video-vesa xf86-input-libinput dwm && \
    echo "allowed_users=anybody" > /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config && \
    echo "needs_root_rights=yes" >> /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config && \
    adduser -S dwm -s /bin/sh && \
    addgroup -S -g $DOCKER_GROUP_ID dwm && \
    addgroup dwm dwm && \

USER dwm

WORKDIR /home/dwm

ENTRYPOINT ["run"]
```

`run` script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
startx /usr/bin/dwm :1
```

But right after that, my container doesn't work anymore, whenever i try to launch it, it freezes and i have to kill it manually, no errors appear, from what i could find on Xorg logs, it's a permission problem on `/dev/tty0`, but i still couldn't figure out how to make it work

> **EDIT:** after adding my container user to the `tty` group, the error changed to `xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open virtual console 7 (permission denied)`

Comment: Are you actually trying to run an X server on the host hardware, not just trying to run an application on the existing display?  Would a virtual machine be a better way to achieve this setup?  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] and not just the error message?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm trying to run a X server inside the container, i've added my `Dockerfile` to the question